# VS2019: How do I find `ntddk.h` by using CMake on windows?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, wdk

New to visual studio, now I wanted to build a simple windows driver filter application which requires `ntddk.h`, but unfortunately I cannot make it work after few hours searching.

I am using VS2019 16.10.4 (community version), and I've installed windows SDK:

[image]

Now the problem is, even I set `CMAKE_VS_WINDOWS_TARGET_PLATFORM_VERSION` to `10.0.19041.0`, I cannot find the `ntddk.h` header file.

Did I miss something here?

=== UPDATE ===

Here's my CMakeLists.txt by using @Superlokkus's suggestion:

[image]

Comment: You could use https://github.com/SergiusTheBest/FindWDK

Comment: @Superlokkus Thanks so much, but I've tried this repo and it didn't work. The cmake can successfully find WDK module but I don't why my cpp file still cannot load `ntddk.h` or other kernel headers.

Comment: You would have to show your `CMakeLists.txt` then. I suspect you are not using the information that was found in find_package